# Anyway to get dkims records for verifying ses domain in boto?

Tags: boto, amazon-ses

Tinkering around with verifying a couple of domains and found the manual process rather tedius. My DNS controller offers API access so I figured why not script the whole thing.

Trick is I can't figure out how to access the required TXT & CNAME records for DKIMS verification from boto, when I punch in

```
dkims = conn.verify_domain_dkim('DOMAIN.COM')
```

it adds DOMAIN.COM to the list of domains pending verification but doesn't provide the needed records, the returned value of dkims is

```
{'VerifyDomainDkimResponse': {
    'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'REQUEST_ID_STRING'},
    'VerifyDomainDkimResult': {'DkimTokens': {
        'member': 'DKIMS_TOKEN_STRING'}}}}
```

Is there some undocumented way to take the REQUEST_ID or TOKEN_STRING to pull up these records?

---

**UPDATE**

If you have an aws account you can see the records I'm after at

https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/home?region=us-west-2#verified-senders:domain

tab: Details:: Record Type: TXT (Text)

tab: DKIM:: DNS Record 1, 2, 3

these are the records required to add to the DNS controller to validate & allow DKIM signatures to take place

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it with python.

```
DOMINIO = 'mydomain.com'

from boto3 import Session
session = Session(
    aws_access_key_id=MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name=MY_AWS_REGION_NAME)
client = session.client('ses')

# gets VerificationToken for the domain, that will be used to add a TXT record to the DNS
result = client.verify_domain_identity(Domain=DOMINIO)
txt = result.get('VerificationToken')

# gets DKIM tokens that will be used to add 3 CNAME records
result = client.verify_domain_dkim(Domain=DOMINIO)
dkim_tokens = result.get('DkimTokens')  # this is a list
```

At the end of the code, you will have "txt" and "dkim_tokens" variables, a string and a list respectively.

You will need to add a TXT record to your dns, where the host name is "_amazonses" and the value is the value of "txt" variable.

Also you will need to add 3 CNAME records to your dns, one for each token present in "dkim_tokens" list, where the host name of each record is of the form of **[dkimtoken]._domainkey** and the target is **[dkimtoken].dkim.amazonses.com**

After adding the dns records, after some minutes (maybe a couple of hours), Amazon will detect and verify the domain, and will send you an email notification. After that, you can enable Dkim signature by doing this call:

```
client.set_identity_dkim_enabled(Identity=DOMINIO, DkimEnabled=True)
```

The methods used here are [verify_domain_identity](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.verify_domain_identity), [verify_domain_dkim](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.verify_domain_dkim) and [set_identity_dkim_enabled](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.set_identity_dkim_enabled).
You may also want to take a look a [get_identity_verification_attributes](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.get_identity_verification_attributes) and [get_identity_dkim_attributes](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.get_identity_dkim_attributes).

Comment: Strictly speaking, "use methods X and Y" is an answer (though not a great one).

Comment: I thought it would be enough pointing out the two methods in the official docs. However I went back and improved a little my answer with some code examples. I hope it's ok. That's the way I'm doing it now, and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [get_identity_dkim_attributes](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/ses.html#boto.ses.connection.SESConnection.get_identity_dkim_attributes) method will return the information you are looking for.  You pass in the domain name(s) you are interested in and it returns the status for that identity as well as the DKIM tokens.

Comment: kind of -- it returns {u'GetIdentityDkimAttributesResponse': {u'GetIdentityDkimAttributesResult': {u'DkimAttributes': {}},
  u'ResponseMetadata': {u'RequestId': u'REQUEST_ID_STRING'}}} -- for a non-verified address & a similar dict structure with different values if already confirmed -- not quite what I'm looking for

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are looking for.  What exactly do you need?

Comment: txt & cname records to be added to the domain DNS for validation